# Counting the amount of times a specific key occurs in a multidimensional associative array

Tags: php

I have a multidimensional associative array that I made using the following code:

```
$column_data = mysqli_fetch_fields($result);
$column_total = json_decode(json_encode($column_data), TRUE);
return $column_total;
```

The reason is I want to know how many columns are returned from a mysqli query. So I fetched the fields used json e.c.t to turn it into an array hoping that I would find a nice simple way to count the number of times the [name] key occurs.

The I searched two columns email and password in my query and the array looks like the following:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => email
            [orgname] => email
            [table] => logins
            [orgtable] => logins
            [def] => 
            [db] => staff_members
            [catalog] => def
            [max_length] => 23
            [length] => 255
            [charsetnr] => 8
            [flags] => 16388
            [type] => 253
            [decimals] => 0
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => password
            [orgname] => password
            [table] => logins
            [orgtable] => logins
            [def] => 
            [db] => staff_members
            [catalog] => def
            [max_length] => 60
            [length] => 255
            [charsetnr] => 8
            [flags] => 0
            [type] => 253
            [decimals] => 0
        )

)
```

And what I am trying to do is count the number of times the [name] key occurs within this array.

If I search one column and use the following code:

```
$column_count = count(array_keys($result,'Name'));
```

Then I get the result 1 as expected. However when I search for multiple columns like above this does not work because the $column_data array has multiple indexes.

Is there a way for me to get a the sum total of times the [name] key appears in the $column_total array without having to do a foreach loop?

My desired outcome is I want a function that takes a query result works out how many columns are in the result and returns either:

A. 1 single variable named after the column containing the value like so:

```
$column_name = $column_value;
```

B. If multiple columns are selected then just return an associative array using

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $data[] = $row;
} 


So yeah how can I can get the sum total of the amount of times [name[ is in the array above?
```

Comment: `count(mysqli_fetch_fields())` will tell you how many fields there are - every result is a column. Also there's [`mysqli_num_fields()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.field-count.php) that can tell you this numbger directly.

Comment: That is what im using at the moment but I am hoping to get the count of the number of times the "name" field is in the object, basically what im hoping to achieve is to work out how many column names where returned from the mysqli query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 function countKeyInArray($key, array $array)
{
    $keys = array();
    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        $keys[] = $key;
        if (is_array($array[$key])) {
            $keys = array_merge($keys, array_keys_multi($array[$key]));
        }
    }

    return substr_count(serialize($keys), $key);
}
```